# How do I loop this program?

Tags: python, loops

Once the program prints, it shuts down. How do I make it returns to the top of the code so that it loops, indefinitely asking for the users name?

code:

```
from time import sleep

name = raw_input ("Please enter your name: ")

print "Hello", name, "- good to see you!"
sleep(2.00)
```

pseudo-code:

```
from time import sleep

A
name = raw_input ("Please enter your name: ")

print "Hello", name, "- good to see you!"
sleep(2.00)
return to A
```

Comment: Did you even read a single thing on python? how did you know how to import a module without knowing what a loop is

Comment: And of course the pseudocode uses goto. "Dijkstra would not have liked this" ;)

Comment: This was a test program for a program I'm working on. I was having a problem so I was tying to obtain the behavior I wanted on a simplified level. Because the normal loop method was not working.

Answer (score 6):

```
while True:
    # do something
    # do something else
    # do more things
```

For your specific example:

```
from time import sleep

while True:
    name = raw_input ("Please enter your name: ")

    print "Hello", name, "- good to see you!"
    sleep(2.00)
```

The general format of this loop is as follows:

```
while <condition>:
    <code>
```

Each time the loop runs, it checks to see if `<condition>` is a true value (`True` obviously is, but you can also have more complex conditions like `foo < 3` or the like). If it is, then it runs `<code>`, then repeats. If it isn't, then it finishes looping and moves on in the rest of the program.

There's more information on looping [in the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques).

Answer (score 5):

You should read some basic documentation, like this: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import sleep

while True:
    name = raw_input ("Please enter your name: ")

    print "Hello", name, "- good to see you!"
    sleep(2.00)
```

Comment: seems I was a little bit slow

Answer (score -3):

two methods can done.
1. use "do-while"
2. use "while(true) and if to break"

Comment: Python doesn't have a do-while